# There are exceptions—two "of them"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

> As always, there are exceptions—two **of them**.

I take it here "of them" means something on the lines of "to be precise", similarly to "[that makes two of us](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/that-makes-two-of-us)".

But what's the exact meaning of **of** here?
https://oed.com/oed2/00162372

Comment: ***Of*** those things that might be labelled "exceptions", ***two*** can be identified in the present context.

Comment: 42a, I would say. It doesn't mean _to be precise_, just _two of the things previously mentioned_.

Answer (score 0):

The closest usage from https://oed.com/oed2/00162372 would be:

> (42. a. Preceded by a word of number or quantity.)

In your example, "of them" does not mean "to be precise" (nor is it used that way in "that makes two of us").

The phrase "of them" is a way of associating a count backward with the object being counted, where a number on its own would be insufficient. This is often used as an additional specification after an otherwise complete sentence (e.g. your "There are exceptions."). E.g.:

- "I actually do have children -- 3 of them."

Comment: What's the difference between _"I actually do have children -- 3 (of them)."_?

Comment: The difference between that and what?

Comment: The versions with and without **_of them_** in _What's the difference between "I actually do have children -- 3 (of them)_.

Comment: Ah, ending the sentence with "3" (without "of them") is probably ok, but feels abrupt, and how you would say it more confrontationally with emphasis on the number. Adding "of them" is simply more natural.